# case insensitive search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, case-insensitive

I have tried making an entry in the elasticsearch.yml file to create the custom analyser for the same as mentioned in the gist: https://gist.github.com/1403902

but i am getting following error 
`{"error":"RemoteTransportException[[Banner, Robert Bruce][inet[/192.168.1.15:9300]][indices/create]]; nested: MapperParsingException[mapping [type1]]; nested: MapperParsingException[Analyzer [string_lowercase] not found for field [field1]];`

I am still not able to figure out how to do this. I have searched stackoverflow for the same and  got similar replies (as mentioned in the gist mentioned above)

please provide me an example, that i can test.

Comment: The example provided in the gist works. Perhaps the issue is in how the custom analyzer was specified in your elasticsearch.yml file. Could you post your elasticsearch.yml file somewhere? Another possibility is that you are running several elasticsearch nodes and the changes in elasticsearch.yml were not made on all nodes or not all nodes were restarted after the changes were made.

Comment: @imotov  Thanks for the help, I did not restart any node. Please point me to the document, that has information on how to restart nodes.  about the elasticsearch.yml, i just copied the analyzer yml at the end of the file. here is the link to my elasticsearch.yml  https://gist.github.com/3177215

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since config file is read only on startup, for the changes to take effect, you need to restart the elasticsearch cluster. You can use [Shutdown API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-cluster-nodes-shutdown.html) for that, or simply kill elasticsearch processes using kill command.

Comment: thanks imotov. That really helped. By the way, the link for shutdown api is broken.

Comment: The link is correct, but elasticsearch.org website is down at the moment.