# How can an Elasticsearch index be made globally case-sensitive?

Tags: elasticsearch, case-sensitive

By default, ES is case-insensitive. There are examples ( eg [case insensitive search in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638676/case-insensitive-search-in-elasticsearch) ) of how to define an analyzer for a specific field in ES.

I have a large number of data types with varying fields being loaded, and it's totally impractical for me to set the analyzer on fields by name.

I was previously using Solr, and accomplished a globally case-sensitive search by using dynamicFields for all of my data, and editing schema.xml to modify the "text" fieldtype to remove the LowerCaseFilterFactory from the analyzer.

How can I do something similar in ES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the elasticsearch documentation for the [Analysis index module](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/). There's a Default analyzers section which says:

> The default logical name allows one to configure an analyzer that will
>   be used both for indexing and for searching APIs. The default_index
>   logical name can be used to configure a default analyzer that will be
>   used just when indexing, and the default_search can be used to
>   configure a default analyzer that will be used just when searching.

I guess that is what you're looking for. Probably good to know that the default analyzer in elasticsearch is the [StandardAnalyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/standard-analyzer.html).